# Weird AfterInsert

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have two Domain class

```
class Reputation {
    int value
    static hasMany = [events: Event]
    static mapping = {
         value defaultValue: 0
  }
}
```

and

```
class Event {
    int     point   
    static belongsTo = [reputation: reputation]
}
```

In ReputationService, I do something like this

```
reputation.addToEvents(new Event())
reputation.save() //which gonna make event and reputation save at once
```

But I want value in Reputation to be updated to : value is the sum of all events' point. So I add :

```
Class Event {
    //....
    def afterInsert() {
    reputation.value += point
    reputation.save()
    } 
}
```

But it doesn't work: I always have a Reputation.value = 0.

What is wrong ? And how can I do this properly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) regarding Events and GORM you will notice it says:

> Since events are triggered whilst Hibernate is flushing using
>   persistence methods like save() and delete() won't result in objects
>   being saved unless you run your operations with a new Session.

So, in your case it may be something like this:

```
Class Event {
    //....
    def afterInsert() {
      Event.withNewSession {
        reputation.value += point
        reputation.save()
      }
    } 
}
```